# Top Level Domain (.com) and subdirectories for each country: Do they need their own content to rank in Google?

Tags: seo, google, country-specific, subdirectory

If I want to have a new site with a `.com` domain and have a `/uk/` and `/au/` folder for ranking in the Google results for each country, do I need to create a `/uk/blog/` and a `/au/blog/` to get content for the `/uk/` site and the `/au/` site?

Or can I go with `mydomain.com/blog/` with `mydomain.com/uk/` and `mydomain.com/au/` for each country with the `mydomain.com/blog/` content counting towards the ranking and backlinks for both `/uk/` and `/au/`?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you use subdirectories with gTLDs (e.g., `mydomain.com/uk/` and `mydomain.com/ua/`) to target site content to a specific country, you should place that content within the country specific subdirectory (e.g., `mydomain.com/uk/blog/` and `mydomain.com/ua/blog/`).

According to Google, although it's strongly recommended to provide unique content to each group of users, it does understand if similar content appears in URL structures like the above that it recognizes, as listed under the "URL structures" and "Duplicate content and international sites" sections here:  [Google Webmaster Tools - Multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2)

Since all of this content is located on the same domain, any links between the subdirectories/countries and other directories would be considered [internal links](http://moz.com/learn/seo/internal-link), not backlinks coming from external domains. There is an SEO benefit with internal links too however, as covered in that link. And each internal link found within your content and sitemaps(s), which can target [multiple countries](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587), will be crawled and indexed as well.

Comment: What I mean is, if I create mydomain.com/uk/ and mydomain.com/au/ will Google consider those sites with 1 page or will Google count the mydomain.com/blog/ content as being on the same site, I do not want the mydomain.com/blog/ content to rank in Google, I just want to create a minimum of 30-50 pages so that the site isn't small. Google doesn't like small sites, remember?

Basically, I want to know if I have to write 30 pages of content for mydomain.com/uk/ and 30 new pages again for mydomain.com/au/ to get the /uk/ site ranking in Google UK and the /au/ site ranking in Google AU?

Comment: Going off the last question in your comment: Google ranks pages not sites, and evaluates each page based on its own merits, including authoritative links from other domains (backlinks). In terms of size, Google is fine with small websites, including single pages sites: [What does Google think of single-page websites?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mibrj2bOFCU). So no, you don't have to write 30 new pages of content for each country, just at least one good one :-)

Comment: But as the first link in my answer indicates, Google is less concerned with duplicate content between country sites on the same domain, providing you don't use two different URL's to the same country (see the bottom section of that first link).

Comment: So, Google AU will count mydomain.com/blog/ pages and links to those pages when evaluating the ranking of mydomain.com/au/ ? I am not concerned about internal links. I am asking if a 1 page site such as mydomain.com/au/ will benefit from links to pages on mydomain.com/blog/ or mydomain.com/uk/ when ranking in Google AU (eg. AU ranking for the /au/ "site")?

I want to create a lot of content on mydomain.com/blog/ and this makes the mydomain.com an authoritative domain and this will make ranking the mydomain.com/au/ easier than using a mydomain.com.AU domainm right?

Comment: Keep in mind that `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com/au` are the same domain, and any links under the same domain are [internal links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_link). You can get somewhat of a boost from authoritative internal links _if_ the page that's linking to it is an _authoritative_ source on its own. You'll receive more of a boost however from a link from an authoritative page on a _different_ domain (i.e., [backlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink)).

Comment: So to answer the last question in your comments, creating a lot of content elsewhere on the same domain isn't going to cause another page in a subdirectory to rank higher - only good quality content for that page, with authoritative internal and external links (with an emphasis on the later) will cause _individual_ pages in your country specific subdirectories to rank higher. Hope this is clear now :-)

Comment: so making mydomain.com an authority domain will not help mydomain.com/au/ and mydomain.com/uk/ rank just because they are on mydomain.com? That is the way it usually works for my other sites, so basically you are saying only mydomain.com/au/ subfolder will get mydomain.com/au/ ranking in Google AU?

Basically the answer to my original questions is no... content outside of the mydomain.com/au/ folder does not count towards the ranking of mydomain.com/au/?

Obviously that page will have on-page SEO and 500+ words of original, well-written content.

Comment: _If_ `mydomain.com` has good quality pages on it that rank well, and not just "a lot of content" as stated above, then you will likely gain authority and trust for that domain over time, which might be inherited by pages in subdirectories. However, that is just _one_ metric used by search engines, and doesn't solely ensure that a regionalized page will rank well against others in the same regional search engine. You still need good quality content in that page (as you pointed out in your last comment), with authoritative linking.

Comment: So in summary: Yes, you need (good quality) separate content for each regional site, though Google is somewhat lenient on duplicate content issues as covered above. And one regionalized website doesn't completely ensure that another will rank well. Building and maintaining SEO for multi-regional websites takes work. Good luck!